# MySQL Table Alias

Tags: mysql, view

I'm migrating an application from a case insensitive database to MySQL. My DBA does not permit changing any Mysql configuration settings so using the "lower_case_table_names" is not an option.

Does MySQL have any aliasing ability to have multiple table names point to the same table?

For example, if USER and usersB were aliased to the same table, then these two queries would insert into the same table:

```
Insert into USER VALUES (2, 3....);
```

and

```
Insert into usersB VALUES (2, 3, ....);
```

Views come close to the desired functionality, but I would like to have update and alter structure commands work against all of the aliases.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> Does MySQL have any aliasing ability to have multiple table names point to the same table?

There is no such SQL convention - an INSERT statement inserts record(s) into one, and only one, table.  User defined types might, but MySQL doesn't support them.

A view can be used to present a unified resultset - IE:

```
CREATE VIEW vw_users AS
   SELECT * FROM USER
   UNION 
   SELECT * FROM USERSB
```

...and are potentially updateable, but will not work for your desired functionality.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but I'm actually looking for something slightly different: one table accessed by MANY names. For example, there would be a single table named user, but client queries might reference USER user777, or UsEr. I have a list of about 10-20 different names which would ideally be aliased to a single physical table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use views and have `UPDATE`s (or any DML) work properly, if you maintain the code for the view. Unfortunately, you cannot have `ALTER` statements (or any DDL) work against all views.  However, when altering the base table, you could regenerate all the views with a single script to make sure that the system is in sync.

As I understood your question, you are talking about views with no joins or unions or even filters -- just `create view USER as select * from usersB`.  Insert, updates, and deletes would work in your example.  ALTERs would not.

Answer (score 0):

One (well three) words: `MERGE storage engine`. See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/merge-storage-engine.html

It's absolutely no problem to have only one table in a `MERGE`, even none would be allowed.

---

Edit: nevermind, ALTER TABLE wouldn't work for this engine (the next operation to the `MERGE` table would fail.

Answer (score 0):

A view is not the same as a table alias (that you can create with the CREATE ALIAS statement in DBMSs that support it) at least until foreign key constraints are supported between tables and views and the client can determine if a view is updatable. MySQL does not. A table alias that can point to a table in a different database is very useful. Feature request.